# How to write a date at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: dates

What is a natural way of writing a date without indication of a year at the beginning of a sentence? Should I use 'On the 3 April', '3d April' or 'On 3 April'.

> **3 April**, the meeting was organized by the representatives of X in the city X.

Answer (score 2):

When we talk about the dates, we use the preposition 'on'.

> ***On*** April 3, ......

I just answered the main question.

There are various ways to write dates. BrE and AmE treat it differently. Good information is here about [how to write dates.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dates)